# Swapping letter casing in Python

Tags: python

Been trying to transition from Java to Python but I am having difficulty writing for loops that iterate through a string.
As you can see, I tried accessing each index to check its case. If that letter is capital then we lowercase it and vice versa.
I'm not really sure why it is returning an unchanged string if I am already making changes to that particular index

```
def swap_case(s):

    for x in range(len(s)):
        if s[x].isupper():
            s[x].lower() 
        if s[x].islower():
            s[x].upper()

    return s
```

Comment: Strings are immutable. `s[x].lower()` returns a new string, you have to do something with it.

Comment: If s is a string then you can just do `s.swapcase()`

Comment: also, your two conditions will override one another due to missing elif

Comment: You're not saving the results and you're not calling `upper` either.

Comment: Note, strings are immutable in Java too.

Comment: Is `s` a string or a list? Question says "iterate through a list" but then says "returning an unchanged string"

Answer (score 4):

If s is a string you can do the following:

```
def swap_case(s):
    return s.swapcase()
```

That being said, I don't think you need to create a function if that is all you are doing. You can just call .swapcase() on the string rather than passing it into a function.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, strings are immutable. Therefore, you can use a list comprehension with `.join`:

```
def swap_case(s):
   return ''.join([i.lower() if i.isupper() else i.upper() for i in s])
```

Comment: Strings are immutable, you can't assign to `s[x]`.

Comment: @Barmar correct, however, the OP mentioned that he is iterating over a list, not a string.

Comment: You can remove the `[...]` and use a generator comprehension instead, which should be negligibly faster.

Comment: nit: i wouldn't use `i` for a character in a string. `i` is never anything but an index in my head. I'd prefer `c` or `ch`. (I mention mostly because when I skimmed this answer I thought "Hey you can't lowercase an index!")

Comment: @TemporalWolf generally yes, however, in the case of `join`, it still has to format the passed generator to a list, so it is actually more efficient to pass a list.

Answer (score 1):

For a recursive solution:

```
def swap_case(s):
    if not s:  # empty string
        return s
    head, tail = s[0], s[1:]
    if head.isupper():
        return head.lower() + swap_case(tail)
    else:
        return head.upper() + swap_case(tail)
```

This is not ideally performant in Python (which generally implements recursion poorly under the hood), but it's not all that bad for reasonably-sized strings.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have mentioned, `s[x].lower()` returns a new string, and it can't be assigned to since strings are immutable. So you need to accumulate a new string.

```
def swap_case(s):
    s0 = ""
    for x in range(len(s)):
        if s[x].isupper():
            s0 += s[x].lower() 
        elif s[x].islower():
            s0 += s[x].upper()
    return s0
```

You can also iterate over it with a lambda, which will be more concise.

```
def swap_case(s):
    s0 = map(lambda x: x.lower() if x.isupper() else x.upper(), s)
    return ''.join(s0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python you don't need to loop over strings like `for x in range(len(s))`. Instead python can be more succinct with `for char in message`. Furthermore the `if` clause looks like it should be followed by an `elif` and an `else` (for non alphabetical characters). The code below works well for short messages since `+=` recopies the string each time due to it being an immutable type. If this impacts the speed of your program consider using `str.join()` instead.

```
def swap_case(message):
    swapped_message = ''
    for char in message:
        if char.isupper():
            swapped_message += char.lower()
        elif char.islower():
            swapped_message += char.upper()
        else:
            swapped_message += char
    return swapped_message
```

Comment: Code only answers are not ideal. Please review [answer], then [edit] your answer, including things like *why does it not work the way OP tried* and *how this fixes it*.

Answer (score 0):

See these 2 statements from your code:

```
s[x].lower()
s[x].upper()
```

`s[x]` is *NOT* this (as you may think):

```
+------+------+-----+------+-----+-------------+
| s[0] | s[1] | ... | s[x] | ... | s[len(s)-1] |
+------+------+-----+------+-----+-------------+
                      ^^^^
```

but the *new* 1-character string containing only the `x`<sup>th</sup> character from the original string `s`:

```
+------+------+-----+------+-----+-------------+
| s[0] | s[1] | ... | s[x] | ... | s[len(s)-1] |
+------+------+-----+------+-----+-------------+

                   copy of s[x] 
             (another place in the memory):
                    +------+
                    |      |
                    +------+
                      ^^^^
```

as *it is not allowed to change characters in strings*.

So you changed the case of *that 1-character string*, keeping your original string `s` unchanged.

---

Note:

```
s = "apple"
s = "orange"
```

is perfectly OK - the second statement *didn't change* `"apple"` into `"orange"` but it *created the new string* `"orange"` in an *other place in the memory*, and then *labeled this new place with `s`* (...which was originally the label of the string "apple").